# Is it possible to override a wagtail.hooks.register function with a custom function?

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

Is it possible to override a wagtail `@hooks.register` function with a custom function or to de-register a function all together?

One example of what I would like to achieve is editing the `register_styleguide_menu_item` function in `wagtail/contrib/styleguide/wagtail_hooks.py` so that the style guide is only shown to superusers.

For example; I would like to override the current function:

```py
@hooks.register("register_settings_menu_item")
def register_styleguide_menu_item():
    return MenuItem(
        _("Styleguide"), reverse("wagtailstyleguide"), icon_name="image", order=1000
    )
```

with this:

```py
@hooks.register("register_settings_menu_item")
def register_styleguide_menu_item():
    return AdminOnlyMenuItem(
        _("Styleguide"), reverse("wagtailstyleguide"), icon_name="image", order=1000
    )
```

(note the change from MenuItem to AdminOnlyMenuItem on the third line)

The docs for wagtail hooks are available at https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/hooks.html but it doesn't cover this scenario.

Is there a mechanism to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the menu items based on the `request` you will need to use a different hook.

Either [`construct_main_menu` for the main menu](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#construct-main-menu) or [`construct_settings_menu` for the settings menu](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#construct-settings-menu).

```py
from wagtail.core import hooks

@hooks.register('construct_settings_menu')
def hide_styleguide_menu_item(request, menu_items):
  if not request.user.is_superuser:
    menu_items[:] = [item for item in menu_items if item.name != 'styleguide']
```

Note: the item.name may not be exactly `'styleguide'` it may be `'Styleguide'`.